# Multiplying LongInts. Expression of the form: Int64Var := LongIntVar * LongIntVar

Tags: delphi, pascal

I always thought it was part of the design philosophy in Pascal, that it looked at both the right and left hand sides of an expression when deciding what format/precision to use for an operation. So that, unlike C where an expression like,

```
Float_Var = 1/3
```

results in a value of 0.0 for Float_Var, Pascal always gets this stuff right. :)

So I was kind of surprised when I went to multiply two LongInts (32 bit) to give an Int64 result and found I was getting anomalous results. I had to get all C like and use,

```
Int64_Var := Int64(LongIntVar1) * LongIntVar2
```

to make it work correctly. (BTW. This was under Delphi, various versions tested, but all win32).

I was just wondering if this is an exceptional case in Delphi/Pascal? Or are there other examples where the usual Pascal way, using the types on both sides of an expression to decide on how the operation is performed, doesn't hold.

Comment: a division e.g. 4/2 always results in a float and can't be assigned to an integer, it doesn't matter if all values are Integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I always thought it was part of the design philosophy in
>   Pascal, that it looked at both the right and left hand sides of
>   an expression when deciding what format/precision to use
>   for an operation.

That is not correct. Expressions assignment targets do not influence the evaluation of the expression.

The reason that

```
Float_Var = 1/3;
```

evaluates to 0 in C/C++ is that the / operator is overloaded. It can mean either integer division or floating point division. If one of the arguments is floating point then the operator is floating point division, otherwise, as here, it is integer division.

In Delphi the / operator is not overloaded. It is always floating point division. That's why this code gives a compile error:

```
Int_Var := 1/3;
```

Comment: Thanks David (and "500"). So when you do something like "**WordVar:=byte1*byte2**" or "**LongIntVar:=SmallInt1*SmallInt2**" it gets it right, not because it takes the LHS type into consideration when doing the multiplication, but rather because it always does the integer operation in the maximum native integer precision (32 bit on win32) and then downsizes as necessary to make the assignment. Is that basically what's going on?

Comment: Documentation of expressions has this covered. It is here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Arithmetic_Operators  They key part is this: *For other arithmetic operators, the result is of type Extended whenever at least one operand is a real; otherwise, the result is of type Int64 when at least one operand is of type Int64; otherwise, the result is of type Integer. If an operand's type is a subrange of an integer type, it is treated as if it were of the integer type.*

Answer (score 3):

If by "both sides" you mean that it looks at the type of the target variable in an assignment for determining the expression type, then no, that has never been the case. Delphi works like any other mainstream compiler in that regard - that is, the type of an expression is determined from the inside out.