# Wrong value calculated by Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a record declared as

```
T3DVector = record
  X,Y,Z: Integer;
end;
```

One variable **V** of type **T3DVector** holds:

```
V.X= -25052
V.Y=  34165
V.Z=  37730
```

I then try to the following line. **D** is declared as *Double*.

```
D:= (V.X*V.X) + (V.Y*V.Y) + (V.Z*V.Z);
```

The return value is: -1076564467 (0xFFFFFFFFBFD4EE0D)

The following code should be equivalent:

```
D:= (V.X*V.X);
D:= D + (V.Y*V.Y);
D:= D + (V.Z*V.Z);
```

But this,however, returns 3218402829 (0x00000000BFD4EE0D), which actually is the correct value.

By looking at the high bits, I thought this was an overflow problem. When I turned on overflow checking, the first line halted with the exception "*Integer overflow*". This is even more confusing to me because **D** is *Double*, and I am only storing values into **D**

Can anyone clarify please ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15400622/33732

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *target* of an assignment statement has no bearing on how the right side is evaluated. On the right side, all you have are of type `Integer`, so the expression is evaluated as that type.

If you want the right side evaluated as some other type, then at least one operand must have that type. You witnessed this when you broke the statement into multiple steps, incorporating `D` into the right side of the expression. The value of `V.Y * V.Y` is still evaluated as type `Integer`, but the result is *promoted* to have type `Double` so that it matches the type of the other operand in the addition term (`D`).

Comment: But - if the values fro V.X and V.Z are switched, then according to your theory, the `D:= (V.X*V.X);` statement should be evaluated as `int` yet it produces the correct result despite `(V.X*V.X)` now exceeding the range of an `int`. I believe it's more complex.

Comment: Huh, @Magoo? The value of 37730 * 37730 is 1,423,552,900, which is less than the maximum `Integer` value of 2,147,483,647.

Comment: Ug. Try 47730 then. Suppose all of the values are such that each square exceeds the limit. I prefer `int64`: `I:=int64(V.X*V.X) + (V.Y*V.Y) + (V.Z*V.Z);` (expression is int64 overall, but `int` for the (V.X*V.X) subexpression) & `I:=int64((V.X*V.X) + (V.Y*V.Y) + (V.Z*V.Z));`  & `I:=(int64(V.X)*V.X) + (V.Y*V.Y) + (V.Z*V.Z);` produce incorrect results but `I:=(int64(V.X)*V.X) + (int64(V.Y)*V.Y) + (int64(V.Z)*V.Z);` is fine. Each *subexpression* must be correctly typed. Naturally, in a serious language like COBOL ((duck)) the intermediate results are determined at max-precision.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `D` is a double doesn't affect the type of X, Y and Z. Those are `Integer`s, and are apparently not large enough to store the squares of such large numbers, and their multiplication is what overflows. Why don't you declare them as doubles, too?